# Access forbidden after using FileZilla client

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd

I'm running apache2 webserver on raspberry pi and when I transfered few files from my PC to raspberry (via FileZilla client), I have no Access to them:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /srs_stuff.php on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at 10.10.10.110 Port 80
```

When I want Access to old files it Works without any problems, however this error is shown when I try to gain Access to new files.

I have no httpd.conf file (?), but I have apache2.conf file where this sections is present:

http://puu.sh/mVsB4/fdf059703b.png

Comment: Check the file access rights in your apache document root`/var/www` with the `ls -l ` command. The apache user (`www-data`) should have at least the read permission.

Comment: First instead of linking to a picture include the details in your question. Second as ripat mentioned please also include the output of ls -la /var/www and /var/www/html to your question. The problem is likely the result of incorrect file permissions/ownership. You may want to look at the chown and chmod commands. You can do that with the following command man chown amd man chmod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dot-files are **NOT** for web and HTTP protocols, so your `apache2.conf` is correct. Use SFTP(FTP insife SSH) - FileZilla also supports it - and don't forget to check in with the **same** user, that will be accessing it, like `www-data` for static files and `www` for dynamic scripts. It's not a requirement to have a separated user for PHP scripts, by the way, but never the less - pay attention to access rughts. CHMOD command will be at help